# Can I add charset from utf-8 to utf8mb4 in django databases

Tags: mysql, django

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
   'NAME': '{{projectName}}',
   'USER': 'root',
   'PASSWORD': 'root',
   'HOST'strong text: 'localhost',
   'PORT': '3306',
 }
}
```

How i can add or update charset, For Options Key i kept charset key getting error like below

conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)

TypeError: 'charset' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

For mysql database there is option like charset

Answer (score 0):

You will try use the OPTIONS key, it works for me

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
   'NAME': '{{projectName}}',
   'USER': 'root',
   'PASSWORD': 'root',
   'HOST'strong text: 'localhost',
   'PORT': '3306',
   'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
 }
}
```